# Sorting a jquery datatable based on a calcul between two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a [jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/) that's initialized and populated using ajax.
I have a menu on the left with various "complex" sorting options.

My datatable contains a total price as well as the number of units sold.
I don't have and can't add a column "unit price" but i still would like my menu item "Sort by unit price" to work as intended which means that if i have the following table :

```
Name    Units    Price
----------------------
James   1        10
Eric    2        19
Greg    10       110
James   5        45
```

And i click on that button, i want it to be sorted like that :

```
Name    Units    Price
----------------------
James   5        45
Eric    2        19
James   1        10
Greg    10       110
```

I want to do this purely in javascript cause i don't want to mess with the controllers and models.

Comment: have you tried putting in your datatable something like this `"aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]]` ?

Comment: Impossiple to produce an answer when we cant reproduce the scenario. You must figure out how to make a customsort http://www.datatables.net/development/sorting#data_source that operates on the secret unit price on a hidden field, when you hit that "complex sort" button.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for pointing this out. It allowed me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this using the following:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['unit-price'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn ) {
    return $.map( oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings), function (tr, i) {

        var price = parseInt($('td:eq('+iColumn+')', tr).text());
        if(isNaN(price)) return 0;

        var units = parseInt($('td:eq(1)', tr).text());
        if(isNaN(units)) return 0;

        var result = Math.round(1000*price/units);
        return result;

    } );
};
```

For now i'm keeping the fact that the units column is at index 1 but one could use a class for instance to keep this dynamic.

And then initializing in the datatable with:

```
theTable.dataTable({
    ...
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sSortDataType": "unit-price" }
    ]
});
```

I can now sort it with an external button using:

```
theTable.dataTable().fnSort([[5,'asc']]);
```